# Listing all calls from an erlang module

Tags: module, erlang

I'm an Erlang beginer and I'd like to find a way to list all the methods available for a given module. What's the best way?
In my case, the module is `ejabberd_odbc`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call `Modulename:module_info()` to get information on the module in a proplist form. To get exports only, call `Modulename:module_info(exports)`.

Comment: A simpler way is to call m(Modulename) in the shell.

Answer (score 0):

I'm always checking the `exports` section in the source of the module.

Answer (score 0):

There is a tool you can install called edoc, whose manual is at: http://www.erlang.org/doc/man/edoc.html This allows javadoc style documentation to be generated for Erlang modules.

Also there is ejabberd_odbc documentation at: http://www.process-one.net/docs/ejabberd/devdoc/trunk/ejabberd_odbc.html